# What is the event for FB subscribe when user edits comment

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a page with plugin facebookcomment and using FB.subscribe when user create a new comments with event like

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function (response) {alert(response.CommentID);})
```

My question is:
If user edit comment, what event should I use as parameter of subscribe, I try `comment.edit` it does not work

Is there anyway for subscribing when user edits his comment?

Comment: No, I don’t think there is any. (And the documentation doesn’t even appear to list `comment.create` as a valid event any more, so even that might stop working at some point.)

Comment: OK thanks a lot, do you know some way to  check if user has edited his comment  on plugin facebookcomment

Comment: Other than regularly fetching all the comments and comparing them to what you have already stored - no.